# Should I close log file in Go?

Tags: logging, go

I created a Global `Logger` in a utils package's `init()` method.

```

```
 package utils

 var Logger *log.Logger

 func init() {

  logFile, _ := config.Configure.String("log_file")
  if len(logFile) == 0 {
     appRoot, _ := os.Getwd()
     logFile = filepath.Join(appRoot, "app_runtime.log")
  }

  f, err := os.OpenFile(logFile, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
  //Look HERE!!! 

  if err != nil {
     panic(err)
  }
  Logger = log.New()

  //Log as JSON
  Logger.Formatter = &log.JSONFormatter{}

  //Output to stdout
  //When production, use file
  Logger.Out = f

  // Only log the debug severity or above.
  Logger.Level = log.DebugLevel
}
```

```

So, I can use it like this:

`utils.Logger.Info("This is debug info")`

My question is: Should I close the log file? How?

Comment: Maybe I don't need it, since handle will close on executable exit???

Comment: Which logger package do you used? The standard `log` package does not export its `out` member.

Comment: https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, [`os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) will be finalized by the Garbage Collector (GC) when application exit. From [`SetFinalizer`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetFinalizer) documentation

> The finalizer for obj is scheduled to run at some arbitrary time after obj becomes unreachable. There is no guarantee that finalizers will run before a program exits, so typically they are useful only for releasing non-memory resources associated with an object during a long-running program. For example, an os.File object could use a finalizer to close the associated operating system file descriptor when a program discards an os.File without calling Close, but it would be a mistake to depend on a finalizer to flush an in-memory I/O buffer such as a bufio.Writer, because the buffer would not be flushed at program exit.

If you don't want to rely on GC, you can close it manually in the `main` function as follows:

```
func main() {
    //Close log writer when exit
    defer func(){
        if file, ok := Logger.Out.(*os.File); ok {
            file.Sync()
            file.Close()
        } else if handler, ok := Logger.Out.(io.Closer); ok {
            handler.Close()
        }
    }()

    //Your original codes
    //...
}
```

In the above code, we use `defer` statement to ensure the *handler* will be closed when the application exit. Since `Logger.Out` may be defined as `io.Writer`, we need to test whether the `Logger.Out` also implements `io.Closer`, and if yes, it will be closed. If `Logger.Out` is an `os.File`, we also call `Sync()` to ensure all the content is written to disk.

**EDIT**
Quote documentation and add `file.Sync()` to ensure file content is written to disk.